# DateTime that adds the specified number of months to the value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Here is my problem.

in c# i can do this using this:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);
```

But i don't know how to do it in JavaScript/jQuery, any ideas ? i'm trying google it, but i only found Converts .... (any tip in how i can search this, will help me too)

Thanks in advance.

PS: I Found this: [A couple of classes featuring the same utilities that .NET classes do.](http://www.menendezpoo.com/index.php?id=5&t=JavaScript-DateTime-and-TimeSpan-Wrappers) , but, can i only achieve this with one "plugin" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 12);
```

Obviously 12 is a bit of a silly example, since it's a whole year...

Oh, and if your new month doesn't have enough days for the old day of month, that then wraps around too, so you have to be careful. For instance:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
if (date.getDate() != day) // day too big, month rolled over
  date.setDate(0); // Use last day of the month
```

Comment: i used 12 too, just cuz i like the number. =)  i'll test this, just one question (if you know will save me time testing) this works with leap year

Comment: If today is the 29th Feb 2012, and you add 12 months, you'll get 1st March 2013, or 28th Feb 2013 with the careful version.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just create Date object and calculate the appropriate seconds to add on.  But to make life easier, why not use something like this: http://www.datejs.com to do the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: +1 Nice Plugin. But i only need this in ONE place. I'm trying avoid put one entire add, just for this.

Answer (score 0):

var date = new Date();
var date6MonthsFromNow = new Date(date.getTime() + (182*24*60*60*1000));

the formula is simply [current time in mils + (#days in 6 months * #hrs in
day * #mins in hrs * #sec in min * #mils in sec)]

Comment: Doesn't the number of days in six months depend on where you start counting from?

Comment: Sure, you'd need to know the actual number of days. Just cut and pasted from the internet... there's no bad code on the internet, right?